# Problem with inheritance

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I created a class:

```
public class AbortableBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
{



  private Thread workerThread;

    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        workerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        try
        {
            base.OnDoWork(e);
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            e.Cancel = true; //We must set Cancel property to true!
            Thread.ResetAbort(); //Prevents ThreadAbortException propagation
        }
    }


    public void Abort()
    {
        if (workerThread != null)
        {
            workerThread.Abort();
            workerThread = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how i use it:

```
  backgroundWorker1 = new AbortableBackgroundWorker();
//...
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy == true)
{
    backgroundWorker1.Abort();//This method is unavailable :(
    backgroundWorker1.Dispose();
}
```

Another small question..will this code cancel a backgroundworker?

Comment: Why do you inherit from `BackgroundWorker` and create then your own thread?

Comment: What type are you creating your AbortableBackgroundWorker as? It looks like you might be creating it as type BackgroundWorker.

Comment: I am looking at a way to abort it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is unavailable because the static type of `backgroundWorker1` is `BackgroundWorker`. You need

```
AbortableBackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new AbortableBackgroundWorker();
```

Otherwise you'll have to downcast it(be it with `(cast)` or `as`) to `AbortableBackgroundWorker`

Comment: @Dmitry: IsBusy should be available... it's a public bool readonly property, so it's inherited as such

Comment: could you answer my second question whether the code above will successfuly abort the backgroundworker

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd - All AbortableBackgroundWorker is a BackgroundWorker.  All BackgroundWorker are NOT AbortableBackgroundWorker and your code would only Abort a AbortableBackgroundWorker.  Of course this doesn't address the fact the entire design is flawed and you would be a fool to actually use it.

Answer (score 6):

It's not the correct way to abort a `BackgroundWorker` task... use the [`CancelAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx) method and the [`CancellationPending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx) property instead. You should almost never abort a thread, at least not when you can exit this tread cleanly.