# Aborting a thread (Backgroundworker).. need an advice

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker

```
        public void ReplayGame()
    {

        if (Class2.replayIsOn)
        {

            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }                 
    }
```

I wan to cancel/stop backgroundwoker1 as soon as the function ends.. the backgroundworker event runs for a few seconds and stops..when it stops I want it to end!!..

How can I achieve that task/? without getting any invalid operation exceptions that i am getting now

UPDATE:

```
    public void ReplayGame()
    {

        if (Class2.replayIsOn)
        {
            replay = serializeMeh.giveBackDictionary();
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }        
    }



    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        int[] makeSelfMoves = new int[4];
        if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            lock (replay)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int[]> item in replay)// count should be more than 2
                {
                    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    makeSelfMoves = replay[item.Key];
                    codeFile.ExecuteAll(makeSelfMoves[0], makeSelfMoves[1], makeSelfMoves[2], makeSelfMoves[3]);
                    PrintPieces(codeFile.PieceState()); Invalid operation exception is thrown here when chess pieces are drawn on the screen ... Two threads enter the loop simultaneously..:(...Invalid operation exception


                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                Class2.counter = serializeMeh.serializedCounter;
                Class2.replayIsOn = false;
                Game.WasntSerialized = true;
            }
        }
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Its unclear what you want to end and when.

Comment: Can't you just call `backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()`?

Comment: Why is it unclear? I said that i want the backgroundworker to end its operation after completing its task in the event of doWork

Comment: Your code sample is not of any help. It is unclear what you are trying to do. And there is nothing in the code that would indicate an error to be thrown.

Comment: @Dmitry, why is it waiting a few seconds. Once it ends it ends. Show us some of your code for the background worker events

Comment: @Dmitry: Why not let `DoWork` end gracefully then?

Comment: updated answer... I want at the end of the event ..(after the loop), the worker to end!!!!

Comment: because i get operation invalid ..object is in use by the user..each time it runs with a few more threads.. (The Replay function is called each time i click on a button, creating another thread and thats what is causing the exception...I think).

Comment: The Bgw _is_ stopping where you set the e.Cancel. Your problem is not where you think it is.

Comment: You keep asking the same question and you keep getting told the same answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778046/problem-with-inheritance you need to call CancelAsync. Update your question to include your current problems ( remove the previous problems ) since your previous method wasn't correct.  I want to see you post the exact exception you are getting.

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd - You updated the code.  What exception are you getting now exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check that the worker support cancellation?

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

If you haven't explicitly set it and you call

```
backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
```

*InvalidOperationException* will be thrown, because by default worker doesn't support asynch cancellation.

**UPDATE**
That's just the property that checks the workers's state, if you need to cancel the work you need to call `backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();`

See a sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: @Dmitry pls see the update, you cannot cancel the work by assigning the true value to `Cancel`. That property is just a state indicator, you need to call the method.

Comment: I updated my answer. If the backworker is busy cancel it....This will terminate its operation.. updated answer above

Answer (score 2):

You are only checking to see if cancellation is pending once before you start your loop, then never check it again. You need to check every iteration through the loop:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int[] makeSelfMoves = new int[4];
    {
        lock (replay)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int[]> item in replay)// count should be more than 2
            {
                makeSelfMoves = replay[item.Key];
                codeFile.ExecuteAll(makeSelfMoves[0], makeSelfMoves[1], makeSelfMoves[2], makeSelfMoves[3]);
                PrintPieces(codeFile.PieceState());

                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                    break;

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Class2.counter = serializeMeh.serializedCounter;
            Class2.replayIsOn = false;
            Game.WasntSerialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dmitry, I can't know what you're talking about until you post the error. Or is it an exception?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that:

```
if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)              
{                    
backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();              
}                
if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)              
{
replay = serializeMeh.giveBackDictionary();                  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();              
}
```

really should be:

```
if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)              
{                    
backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();              
}                
else
{
replay = serializeMeh.giveBackDictionary();                  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to call `CancelAsync`. Then you need to check the `CancellationPending` property using a [guard clause](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) with a `return` statement.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // A bunch of stuff here.

    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending) return;

    // A bunch of stuff here.
}
```

Comment: See the answer that i have updated, I think I am in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that cancelling the `BackgroundWorker` at the end of the DoWork callback is unnecessary? By design, the `BackgroundWorker` does stop working when the DoWork callback exits; at this point the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is raised just like it would be after calling `CancelAsync()`.

Unless I'm missing something in the original question, I don't see how the default behavior is any different and why cancelling the worker would be preferred?